# ClassLoader not recognizing programmatic jar file

Tags: jar, zip, classloader

I have a program that creates java source code files, compiles them to create class files and “jars up” the classfiles into a jar using java.utils.jar. When the resulting jar is placed in a lib directory in another application, the classes are supposed to be recognized. Except the created classfiles are not being recognized. So I used WinZip to zip the same class files, renamed the “zip” a “jar”, placed the new jar in the lib directory and the files are recognized fine. Used WinZip to look at the first (programmatically-produced) jar and the WinZip-created jar and they look identical. Same paths, same original size, same compressed size. Also tried creating a zip via java.utils.zip and renaming it. Same problem. Does anyone know of any reason why the programmatic zip/jar files could not be recognized by the Java class loader?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Maybe this will help others. The argument to ZipEntry (and JarEntry) must use forward slash ("/") as the name separator in order for the ClassLoader to correctly recognize the included files. In particular, other separators, such as those returned by File.getAbsolutePath(), while seemingly happily accepted by java.utils.jar and WinZip, will not be recognized by the ClassLoader.